# How to edit a file in Vim with all lines ending in ^M except the last line ending in ^M^J

Tags: vim

I have a bunch of files that I need to look at. All lines in these files end in ^M (\x0D) except the very last line that ends in ^M^J (\x0D\x0A).

Obviously, Vim determines the filetype to be DOS with the effect that the file's entire content is
displayed on one single line like so:

```
some text foo^Mmore text and^Ma few control-m^Ms and more and more
```

Since I don't want to change the files' content: is there a setting in Vim that allows to look at these
files with the new lines as I'd expect them to be?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not mind having a line at the bottom containing a single `^J` character, you can set `fileformats` (note the `s` at the end) to `mac` and reload the buffer:

```
:set fileformats=mac
:edit
```

Or equivalently you could start the editor as follows:

```
vim -R "+set fileformats=mac" "+edit" <filename>
```

The `-R` (readonly) option is there because you stated you do not want to change the files.

I did not find a way that does not involve reloading the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You helped me figure out that I needed to `set fileformats=dos,unix,mac` instead of `dos,unix`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Can't really verify it though, since I don't have that kind of files handy.

Comment: setting `fileformat` or `fileencoding` while editing a file will not reload it. It will have an effect when saving. Rather do `:e! ++ff=unix` to reload.