# how to change ^M to new line in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit a file in Vim with all lines ending in ^M except the last line ending in ^M^J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562298/how-to-edit-a-file-in-vim-with-all-lines-ending-in-m-except-the-last-line-ending)

i have html file .. one line file .. Has been replaced new line to ^M

But it works well with notepad++

How i can Reformed in vim ?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
:e ++ff=mac
```

<kbd>^J</kbd> = <kbd><LF></kbd> = `\n`
<kbd>^M</kbd> = <kbd><CR></kbd> = `\r`

If the only line separators in your file are `\r`, it uses Mac-style line endings.

Comment: `:e ++ff=mac` only changes how they look. `:%s/\r/\r/g` actually changes them.